# How to store files for thick client app

Tags: oracle, files

How to correctly store files for thick client app (Ora DB <-> Win App)?
A) If we store files in DB, DB is hard to manage and, as I understand, violates best practices.
B) If we store files on disk, then how to access them - windows share is out of question b.c. security and other communication with server is only DB connection.
Any ideas how to store those files and access them to insure security and consistency?
P.S. Redesigning app for web is to expensive.

Comment: What kind of "files" are we talking about?

Comment: Images, pdf, incoming email attachments, office documents, xml reports etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files are "best" managed in a file system.
Files systems *can* be made remotely available through file shares.
Your use case *appears* to preclude the use of these.  That's unfortunate, because it's probably your *easiest* option.

OK, so you need *another* way of getting files from your central location where the files are stored to the client application.

Yes, you *could* put them into the database.
As you say, it's not ideal but it's an option.  You'll need a lot of storage, depending on the files' sizes, but that's just disk space that you'd need anyway.  Retrieving big chunks of data will make queries [a bit] slower but, technically, it's not that big a challenge.

Another, and better, alternative might be to have some *other* piece of software to make your centrally-stored files available to your "remote" application.
That would be a *Web Server*.
Even if you're only operating on an internal network, this is the best tool for the job.  It's scalable, securable and easily operated and - bonus - it acts as a "stepping stone" towards moving your application to the web.

Comment: I agree about Web server, however this solution was turned down as to expensive from developer standpoint. so I was wondering, do Oracle DB have some libraries, to access files directly on disk, not from tables, or there is some open source Web based code to manage file storage for app your way?

Comment: Aargh!  Yet again, Developers that do not want to do /their job/!  I would have expected them to practically "bite your hand off" to get an opportunity to start moving on their "Road to the Web".  
I don't know of any way to "fool" Oracle into passing files around like table data.  To save a few "pennies" on Development, your company will have to waste [many] "dollars" on breaking database Best Practice and putting these files into the database.

Comment: That the thing - project budged don't allow major changes at the moment, so I traying to find solution as DB admin for this. Any how big thanks for your input.
P.S. found this ready to use web solution: https://github.com/jveverka/file-server